# How to backreference this string (php)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, backreference

I am trying to match an "ID" in a string, composed by some numbers (ranging from 1 digit to ~9 (the point is that it has got a variable length). The following code won't backreference my ID, I'm very new to PHP and I've tried google with no good answer.

```
<?php
$to = 'data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=100002781344760">Ae fj';

preg_match('/user.php?id=[\d]+\\"/', $to, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
?>
```

The whole point is to get the "10000278134476" in "/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=100002781344760">". Any useful regexes?

Comment: [Please do not use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/247893)

Comment: Sure don't look like HTML to me

Comment: @James It wouldn't make any sense to use a HTML data attribute in a string for something parsed through AJAX or somewhere where you haven't stripped it off. Of course I can't be sure, I just wanted to make sure that OP and others would know that you shouldn't.

Comment: First: lol nice zalgo text. Second: I just need to parse the id=<number>. I can't even see Murphy's Law meddling in this because it's as basic as "1 == 1".

Comment: @user2079457 If you have no other elements on the page with any attribute, tag name, user string etc. containing `/user.php?id=123`, then sure, you'll be fine. :-)

Comment: Ĭ̘̰̞̪̖̱̞̺̘ͪ̉̓͑ͥ̚͘͜͞͞͡ͅ'̷̷̢̥̱͙̝̩̗̼̪̫̺̺͇͋̋̎̂̋ͤ̾̔̊ͨ̍ͫ̚͡ͅl͎̞͚̬̙̠͎͇̣̗͙̰̗͈̯̯̗̅̒̀͆ͥͣͩ̎ͭ̐̄ͤ͆ͦ̆͆̔ͬ͗̕͝l̛̑́ͮ̂̾̾҉̸̯̫̖̹̺́ ̵̧̫͚̼͎̬̲̄́̔̓͆̾̒̀ͫͭ͌̿̅ͣ̅͑́̚b̶̧̹̗̗͍͚̥͕̬̈ͫ̽͒̑̚͡ḙ̶̭̭͇͎̝̺̭̲͔̬̼̜̭͔̗͈̃̓ͩ̂͛ͫ̆͊̏ͮͧ̅ͭ̓̈́̌͠ ̢̩̳͚̯̹̪̹̞̜͔̙͉̣͕̱͛̃͗ͥͩ̽̇͐ͪ̔̔ͦ̀́͜͠ͅͅf̥̱̻̰̘̻̩͕̳̜̘͙̟̌̃ͭ̄̈́͐ͩͪͫ́ͦ̍̌ͭ̓̆ͥ́͜i̸̬͇̗̘͓̗̞͚͔͖̻̗͙̝̩̳͙̣̿ͨͪͪ̔͂̎ͤ̎ͧ̀ͅn̢̫͈͙̱̞͇͓̹̬̱̬̖͗ͥ͐ͨ͘e̵̺̥͈̻̥̞͙͍͕̣̭̬͈͗̒̿̓͋̕͜,̸̻̳̪͎̲͖͕̘͈͔ͯ͐̄ͯ̍̀̕ ̴̉ͩ̓͐ͫͦ̄͌͐̌́̕͞҉̲̖̼͖͈͎͈̮̤t̡̟̩̭́̒̓ͩ̃̓̇̉̎́͟͝h̢͕͖͈̺͈̫͗ͮ̓͋̄͒͆͌͝ã̢̠̳̬̼̝̇̐͒ͩͦ͂̇̃̎̌̉ͫ͂̉̚͞͡ͅn̡̧̊̃́͂ͬͣͪͧ̂͒͜҉͍̳̝̲͚̰̖͕̣̩͚̳̟͍̬̘k̴̡̢͇̭͇͙̟̗̝̫̦͇̯͇̦͕̈́ͮ̓̄̒̀ͪ̐ͧ̇̃̊̋̋ͨͨ͂͜͢ş̷̷͎̯͖̦̯͖͖̝̰̌̎ͮ͘͡.̷͕̭̩̼̰̮̰̭̦͍͙̝͎͔̱͖̦̓ͨ̑̿̐̑̇̾ͤ̐̈͒̊͛̌́́̕ͅ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `()`s to mark groups should work, or if you want to make it more meaningful you can try named groups with `(?<name>)`:

```
preg_match('/user.php?id=([\d]+)\\"/', $to, $matches);
//                       ^     ^
echo $matches[1]; // capture groups indexed from 1, 0 index is for the whole matched string
```

See the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) for more on the pattern sytnax.

Comment: It does not work for me. "PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in test.php on line 7"

Comment: Your pattern is screwed up, it should be `/user.php\?id=(\d+)/`   Escaping the ? and you dont need to worry about the end quote in fact it could screw up the regex if one url you parse has another parameter.